# Dialog Script break sequence

Tags: linux, ssh, login, account-restrictions

I am trying to create a console based menu for sshing to devices within our network, but I don't want the user to be able to break out of the menu. Would dialog work in this case? If not do I have any other options?

Comment: This menu is for allowing students access to cisco routers for their labs. instead of giving them addresses for the individual routers I would like to create a console server as a front end to the devices. I don't want any students breaking out of the menu and poking around the linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

To prevent them from breaking out of the menu, set it as their shell with `chsh`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @cuonglm I made that an answer because I'm providing the tool to answer his question otherwise if I was going to ask him something about his post I would've made a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the login shell is a step in the right direction, but has a pitfall: it interferes with running scripts by setting `$SHELL`, which is used by many scripts. That is not how `dialog` is supposed to *work*.

Rather, if one sets up an account whose shell *initialization* scripts run your menu script and make the script trap any keyboard interrupt, and logout when the script completes, that will do what was asked.

For example, putting this at the end of `.profile` will only let the account show a message-box:

```
trap "" INT QUIT
dialog --msgbox "Hello World!" 0 0
exit
```

After the `dialog` command completes, the account logs out.  Rather than just running `dialog`, a suitable menu-script could be called without allowing a user access to the filesystem.